# Forward http to https through htaccess with Slim API framework

Tags: .htaccess, api, https, redirect

I'm trying to secure my API which is using the Slim framework and uses an htaccess file to forward all traffic to index.php which allows the API to work.

For example, calling http://api.mydomainname.co.uk/expert/id=MB7763255 works perfectly using the following settings in the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Now I'm trying to force all HTTP traffic to HTTPS and I've tried many variations in the htaccess file which do forward the traffic but then stop my web service working showing "404 not found".

This is what I've been trying:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Or...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%/index.php [R=301,L]
```

Both without success - can anyone point me in the right direction please as I've exhausted Stack Overflow and Google.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it! I'll post this for anyone else experiencing the same issue.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```